# Reusing samples from a probability distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, proof-writing, sampling

I have a *black-box* discrete probability distribution $\mathbf{p}$ (I can only get samples from it), two items in the support: $\sigma_1, \sigma_2$, and a procedure which estimates the following quantity:
$$
r = \frac{\mathbf{p}(\sigma_1)}{\mathbf{p}(\sigma_1)+\mathbf{p}(\sigma_2)}
$$

The procedure runs for $T$ iterations (**$T$ is not known in advance**).

At each iteration $t$, I get a multiset $S_t$ of $n_t$ independent samples from $\mathbf{p}$ conditioned on the set $\{\sigma_1, \sigma_2\}$. Then, my estimate for $r$ is:
$$
\hat{r}_t = \frac{1}{n_t} \cdot \sum_{s \in S_t} [s = \sigma_1]
$$

(where $[P]$ is the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) notation).

Think of this procedure as estimating the bias of a coin, with $\{\sigma_1, \sigma_2\} = \{H, T\}$.

Can I optimize the procedure by reusing the samples from the previous iteration when computing the estimate $\hat{r}_{t+1}$? That is, instead of drawing $n_{t+1}$ samples at the $(t+1)$-th iteration, can I just draw the difference $n_{t+1} - n_t$ and reuse the $n_t$ samples from the $t$-th iteration? Note that $n_1 < n_2 < \dots < n_T$.

Since samples are independent at each iteration, I suppose this is fine.
And if this is the case, my next question is: how to **formally prove** that reusing samples is fine and does not affect the estimate?

---

**Clarifications**

The whole discussion stemmed from the following goal, that is, I want:
$$
\Pr \bigg[ \hat{r} \in \big[r (1-\epsilon), \ r (1+\epsilon) \big] \bigg] \geq 1-\delta
$$
Thus, I have derived a lower bound on the number of samples needed, using a multiplicative Chernoff bound, which yielded:
$$
n = \Theta \left( \frac{1}{(\epsilon \cdot \hat{r})^2} \cdot \log \frac1\delta \right)
$$
so the estimation is part of the bound. To this extent, we need to make reasonable guesses: for the $t$-th iteration, we guess that $r \geq 1/2^t$, and set $\hat{r} = 1/2^t$ in the bound for the number of samples, $n_t$. Then, after sampling $n_t$ values, if we get that the estimate is indeed $\geq 1/2^t$, we stop; otherwise $t \gets t + 1$ and we continue.

It's worth noting that, assuming $r \sim \mathsf{Uniform}(0,1)$, we have that $T \sim \mathsf{Geometric}(1/2)$.

Comment: What is the purpose of the iterations? Aggregating all the data and then looking only on $\hat{r}_T$ is the best option, as it relies on the max amount if IID samples, and we know that the more the merrier in such models.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I have updated the question with some clarifications.

Comment: I assume that the intuition here is that the set of samples that I reuse from iteration $t$ cannot change (in a statistically significant way) the new estimate at iteration $t+1$.